# Click to copy function using JavaScript for blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want someone to explain how to make a layout like below.

[image]

I want when I click on a copy icon only texts available on that box copied. It should be minimum JavaScript for fast loading. Is it possible to make it with less JavaScript which works for each copy icon. Please help me.

here I have done CSS and html please help me with JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<<style>
.box{ width:500px; height:250px; border:1px solid #999; position:relative; margin-top:30px; text-align:center; border-radius: 10px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background:#ebebeb}
.rightCircle{ position:absolute; width:45px; height:45px; border-radius:10%;  background:white; right:5px; top:5px;}
.text-copy{ padding:30px; font-size: 30px}
.imag { padding: 3px; width:35px; height:35px}

</style>
<body>
<div class="box">
  <div class="rightCircle"> <img class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
  <div class="text-copy"> <text-area >text here 1</text-area> </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="rightCircle"> <img class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
  <div class="text-copy"> <text-area >text here 2</text-area> </div>
  
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div class="rightCircle"> <img class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
  <div class="text-copy"> <text-area >text here 3</text-area> </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt so we can help.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Try and I will help using javascript

Comment: @XMehdi01 I am a beginner so please help.

Comment: Do try and I will help you

Comment: your code is very bad structure

Comment: @XMehdi01 please help me to improve it

Comment: @XMehdi01 please help me to improve it

Comment: Your code snippet does not show any attempt at implementing the copy button. Please add your attempts

Answer (score 0):

### If have two answers:

Both use this CSS:

```
<style>
    .box{
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: #ebebeb;
    }
    .rightCircle{
        position: absolute;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        border-radius: 10%;
        background-color: white;
        right: 5px;
        top: 5px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .text-copy{
        padding: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    pre {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .imag {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
    }
    .rightCircle:hover {
        background-color: #99999988;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

**Method 1** (less effort but less customization):

Create a function which copies the `innerHTML` of a element with an `id` to the users `clipboard`; e.g.:

Script:

```
<script>
  const addToClipboard = (id) => {
    const text = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="rightCircle"> <img onclick="addToClipboard('text-one')" alt="copy-symbol" class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
    <div id="text-one" class="text-copy">
      Hello earth!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="rightCircle"> <img onclick="addToClipboard('text-two')" alt="copy-symbol" class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
    <div id="text-two" class="text-copy">
      Hello moon!
    </div>
</div>


<div class="box">
    <div class="rightCircle"> <img onclick="addToClipboard('text-three')" alt="copy-symbol" class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
    <div id="text-three" class="text-copy">
      Hello mars!
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Note, that the element with the id can only exist once, so there is a limit to the styling in your HTML, because it would also copy your HTML-Tags.

**Method 2** (more effort but full control):

In this case you define the text in the function parameters. This way you can seperate your HTML from the copied text. Through this you can change text and HTML independently, but you also have to define each of them.

This gives you more options, when styling your website.

Script:

```
<script>
    const addToClipboard = (text) => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    }
</script>
```

When defining the `onclick function`, you just have to set the `text string` as the `function parameter`.

Like this:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="rightCircle"> <img onclick="addToClipboard('Hello VSauce!\nMichael here.')" alt="copy-symbol" class="imag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Copy_font_awesome.svg/512px-Copy_font_awesome.svg.png"/></div>
    <div class="text-copy"> 
        <pre id="text-one">
            <h2>Hello VSauce!</h2>
            <p>Michael here.</p>
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "syntax" is similar to creating .txt files using the `Blob` object ([Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-and-save-text-file-in-javascript). So "\n" will result in a line break.

Both methods basically use a function called by an onclick attribute in an html to set your cursors clipboard to a defined text.
(`navigator.clipboard.writeText('Text string')`).

Hope it helps